# Need to set timing for this animation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I need to set timing (Delay between two words) in this animation.

I'm following this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Automatic-Text-Rotator-Plugin-with-jQuery-and-Animate-css-cycleText/) for reference.

Provide your suggestions.

Comment: Please add your attempts to do so, so we can help you.

Comment: Nope... We're not here to code stuff for you. And at least, provide your suggestions, _please_.

Answer (score 0):

More details would be useful, but based on what you've given it seems like you can achieve this by using `setTimeout()` function of JavaScript to call a function after a fixed delay.